# Self-host ASP.NET application WITHOUT exposed files

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, self-hosting

I want to self-host an ASP.NET web application from a service that we have developed.  Their are only 2 requirements, the first being no external applications to be redistributed, i.e. no solutions like xsp2 or IIS express, etc.  Second, I'm trying to not leave aspx/code-behind files laying around on the filesystem.  I'd prefer something that can host from embedded resources or from a compiled ASP.NET Web Application (.dll and placeholder aspx files).

I realize that anyone could decompile the binaries, etc, but I'm really just trying to not make it 100% easy to tinker with the web interface.  I've looked at a few options, but none that will properly host a compiled Web Application WITHOUT an external application.

Are there any (preferably 100%-managed) libraries out there that can do this?  Even if it's raw files in a virtual filesystem of some sort (although that would require a driver-installation which I want to avoid).

Comment: Sorry are you asking "how can i host my asp.net webapp without a webserver"?  I

Comment: Not exactly, I'm asking how I can do it in a way that doesn't require an external dependency be installed separate from our application, and also such that the raw aspx and code behind files aren't easily modified when deployed.

Comment: You don't need the code behind anyway. They are all compiled into DLLs in the bin.

Comment: Consider using asp.net precompilation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx this allows you to deploy only the DLLs and empty place-holder files for the aspx files. No source files, no mark-up files.

Comment: I can get as far as a single DLL and the placeholders for the whole web application, the issue then became finding a web server library that would host from THAT.  We tried several and had various issues with each not recognizing that the web application was precompiled or was compiled into a single DLL.

Answer (score 0):

There is one Open Source Embedded C# Web Server on CodePlex but it is not actively developed.
You can however, fork it as per your needs.

http://webserver.codeplex.com/